# Can I use a C# SemaphoreSlim to trigger something

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronization, semaphore

Can a SemaphoreSlim be used (or should it something else?) for one thread to trigger another, and is there a way to clear premature triggers ?
This is async code, so I use "thread" loosely.

```
SemaphoreSlim ready = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);

// Thread 1
...
ready.CurrentCount = 0;  // Can't do this, but somehow clear any premature triggers
DoSomething();           // this will eventually cause other thread to release
await ready.WaitAsync(); // wait for trigger
DoNextThing();
...

// Thread 2
...
ready.Release(); // trigger waiting thread to proceed
...
```

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem. Please explain more about the underlying problem.

Comment: Explain what you whant to achieve. Eg: what's your use case. It would help for answering your question.

Comment: Voting to close... This question needs more clarity, there is already a good answer, but I fear there is sufficient lack of information to do anything other than guess at what you are trying to accomplish and what the actual problem is. You should also read [ask]

Comment: Event objects can be used to **release** other waiting threads. If no other thread is waiting for the object, nothing will happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim) as a coordination primitive for asynchronous workflows. It is well suited for this job. The alternative is to use a [`TaskCompletionSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1). There are pros and cons with each option.

Advantages of the `SemaphoreSlim`:

1. Built in support for optional cancellation, with the overload `WaitAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)`.
2. Built-in support for optional timeout, with the overload `WaitAsync(TimeSpan timeout)`.
3. It is reusable.

Advantages of the `TaskCompletionSource`:

1. Built-in support for asynchronous continuations (option `RunContinuationsAsynchronously`).
2. Can propagate extra state, beyond the signal of completion.
3. Can propagate cancellation and failure.
4. More lightweight than the `SemaphoreSlim`.
5. More expressive regarding its intentions.

The type used for the generic type `TResult` of the `TaskCompletionSource` is usually a `bool` with a completing value of `true`, or an `object` with a completing value of `null`. In most cases the result is irrelevant, so you can choose any type and value you like.

---

**Update:** Here is how you could prevent Workflow 2 from sending signals to Workflow 1, before the later is ready to accept them:

```
private volatile TaskCompletionSource<object> _ready;

// Workflow 1
//...
_ready = new TaskCompletionSource<object>(); // Start accepting signals
DoSomething(); // This will eventually cause other workflow to send a signal
await ready.Task; // Wait for a signal
_ready = null; // Stop accepting signals
DoNextThing();
//...

// Workflow 2
//...
_ready?.TrySetResult(null); // Send signal to waiting workflow, if it accepts signals
```

The [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile) has been added to ensure visibility (that all workflows can "see" the latest value of the `_ready` field). It doesn't enforce any kind of synchronization though. If you want a guarantee that the `_ready` field will be accessed in a specific order, you'll need to add proper synchronization (`lock`, `Interlocked` etc). In that case the `volatile` is redundant and should be removed.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about TaskCompletionSource. It seems like it can also pass data which could be useful for me.
I couldn't think of better than
while (ready.CurrentCount > 0) await ready.WaitAsync();;
to discard spurious triggers as the 2nd thread is receiving data from elsewhere and I only want the instance after the first thread's action.

Comment: @Codemeister I updated my answer with an example of a possible solution to this problem.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you.